# Posso colocar uma imagem da internet num ImageButton?

Tags: android, imagem

É possível criar um `imageButton` e dentro dele colocar uma imagem da *internet*. Consigo fazer isso com a `webView`, mas é possível fazer com o `imageButton`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Julgo que a forma mais simples será esta:

```
URL imageUrl = new URL("url_da_imagem"); 
Bitmap imagem = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
meuImageButton.setImageBitmap(imagem);
```

Fonte [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16293557/2556111)

No entanto o correto é fazer este procedimento num *AsyncTask*:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageButton imageButton;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageButton imageButton) {
        this.imageButton = imageButton;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        URL imageUrl = null;
        try {
            imageUrl = new URL(urls[0]);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap imagem = null;
        try {
            imagem = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imagem;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageButton.setImageBitmap(result);
    }    
}
```

Para colocar a imagem no seu ImageButton faça:

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.doSeuImageButton);
new DownloadImageTask(imageButton).execute("url_da_imagem");
```

É necessário adicionar a seguinte permissão ao *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta, sou iniciante no android e não consegui entender muito bem como posso utilizar, estou estudando e vendo como posso usar. Obrigado

Comment: É fácil. Copie o código da classe `DownloadImageTask` para a *Activity* onde você tem o *ImageButton*. Copie o último código da resposta para dentro do `onCreate` dessa *Activity*. Tem de substituir `R.id.doSeuImageButton` e `url_da_imagem` pelos valores corretos.

Comment: Eu consegui antes de você falar, pesquisei e foi isso mesmo que você disse, agora vou tentar ver como redimensionar a imagem ao imageButton, muito obrigado pela resposta novamente.

Comment: Terá de adicionar `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` ao *AndroidManifest.xml*

Comment: No stackoverflow a melhor forma de agradecer a quem te ajudou é assinalar a melhor resposta e/ou votar naquelas que foram úteis.

Comment: Já fiz isso agradeci. Esse android.permission é para aumentar?

Comment: Para aumentar o quê? A imagem? A permissão é necessária para que a aplicação possa aceder à internet. Sem isso o código não irá funcionar.

Comment: Funcionou sem utilizar o AndroidManifest. ahhhhh mas foi pq eu já tinha utilizado para outra coisa que tentei fazer com webView.

Comment: Seria o tamanho da imagem para se adaptar ao tamanho do imageButton, to procurando pra ver se axo como fazer.

Comment: No *xml* do `ImageButton` coloque estes dois atributos: `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` e `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente você precisa fazer download desta imagem pois não existe uma forma direta de informar uma *URL* diretamente na propriedade `src`, por exemplo.

Você pode ter um método assim, para fazer este o download e obter um `Drawable`:

```
public Drawable drawableFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
    Bitmap x;

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

    x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

    return new BitmapDrawable(x);
}
```

E então, só definir a propriedade do `ImageButton`:

```
btn.setImageResource(drawableFromUrl("http://..."));
```

Não testei, mas provavelmente você terá que fazer isso em uma *thread* diferente da `UI`.