# Como carregar a imagem de um Url em um ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, adapter

```
 rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
            List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
            data = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
            while(rs.next()){
                Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                datanum.put("A", rs.getString("Nome").trim().toString());
                datanum.put("B", "http://acme.com.br/pic/1/" + rs.getString("Al_Matricula").trim().toString() + ".jpg");  // <<<--- URL
                datanum.put("C", rs.getString("Id").trim().toString());
                datanum.put("D", rs.getString("Ean").trim().toString());
                datanum.put("E", rs.getString("Code").trim().toString());
                data.add(datanum);
            }
            String[] from = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
            int[] views = { R.id.tvNome,
                            R.id.tvTemp,   //  <<<----  preciso que meu imageview que esta dentro do listview carregue esta imagem 
                            R.id.tvId,
                            R.id.tvEan,
                            R.id.tvCode };    



        AD = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.activity_modelo, from, views);
        lst_Alunos.setAdapter(AD);
```

Comment: Tem algumas bibliotecas que você pode usar como a picasso ou glide, com elas você consegue um fácil carregamento das imagens a partir da url e ainda consegue manter em cache. [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: Já tentei implementar com Glide e Picasso, porém não estou encontrando como implementar de acordo com a minha necessidade.

Comment: Relacionado: [Posso colocar uma imagem da internet num ImageButton?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57788/2541).

Answer (score 0):

Use a biblioteca **Glide**, segue o exemplo de como implementar no codigo:

```
  Glide.with(this)
                    .load(urlImages.get("SUA URL"))
                    .asBitmap()
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            // AÇÕES A SE EXECUTAR CASO HOUVER ERRO
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, String model, com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            // AÇÕES A SE EXECUTAR QUANDO FOR CARREGADA A IMAGEM
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).into(SUA IMAGEVIEW);
```

Comment: O código que você compartilhou pode ser funcional para outra condição. Não se aplica a minha necessidade . Obrigado pela sua disponibilidade.

Comment: Qual é sua necessidade? Pela pergunta você quer apenas carregar uma url na imageView, e o código  atende a necessidade

Comment: Sua ivImagem está dentro de um item para Listview?

Comment: Se estiver voce tem que executar o codigo no adapter da lista

Comment: Olá Edson!  Talvez eu não tenha sido muito claro.
Eu gostaria de carregar a imagem do "url" na R.id.ivImagem, fiz o cast e tudo mais.
Eu encontrei uma forma de carregar a imagem porém tem que clicar no listView

ImageView iv_Imagem = ( ImageView ) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImagem);
TextView tv_Temp = ( TextView ) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTemp);
String urlImage = tv_Temp.getText().toString();
Picasso.get().load(urlImage).into(iv_Imagem);

Comment: Sim, esta dentro de um ListView

Comment: Como eu faço para executar isso dentro do Adapter, ai é que eu estou me enroscando.

Comment: Cole na sua pergunta o adapter da listview

Comment: A classe que voce monta o adapter e caso tenha a holder separada mande a classe da holder